# PyKDL documentation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to generate a complete html documentation for PyKDL (the version in python_orocos_kdl package in electric)?

So far I've tried using both rosdoc and pydoc. rosdoc outputs an html with only a couple of references to SIP (same as [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/python_orocos_kdl/html/)), and pydoc.writedoc() does somewhat better, but not much.

I guess that this is due to SIP being used to wrap the C++ code, but the whole API is not available and the only way I've found so far to find out the exact python API is reading the .sip files, which is a bit cumbersome.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11235/pykdl-documentation/) by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1071 on 2011-09-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-09-26**:
I just found this http://www.ros.org/doc/api/kdl/html/python/index.html. Not a complete reference either, but definitely better than checking the .sips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've added a sphinx builder configuration to the python_orocos_kdl package. It auto-generates the API for all available classes and functions in the PyKDL module. It uses the docstrings that are added by SIP and only include the API syntax, not the documentation from doxygen. But it gives an overview of what is available. The result can be found at [http://people.mech.kuleuven.be/~rsmits/kdl/python](http://people.mech.kuleuven.be/%7Ersmits/kdl/python)

Ruben

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2012-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of a way to auto-generate the documentation, for the exact same reasons you mention (SIP). The documentation on http://www.ros.org/doc/api/kdl/html/python/index.html is manually generated (and incomplete), but it's the best API documentation of PyKDL I've seen.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1